# Break out of an array of Promises while in .settle() (or equivalent)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

We're currently using `bluebird` `v2.9.8`, unable to upgrade to `v3` for compatibility (for now, but that might not have a solution either).

We've made use of `.settle()` in the past, but we've hit a case where we have a set of `users`, mapped to `promises`, that we need to confirm whether a specific field is `true`.

If there's a single case of `false`, then there's no need to continue. If they were all `true` that would mean we had executed all `promises`.

`Promise.settle()` will execute all, waiting until all are complete.

Again, the goal is to break as soon as we get a `false`.

---

Turns out an additional piece of the code was calling an additional `Promise` to get more info from the db. So, rewritten to use `Promise.all()`:

```
var accessPromises = users.map(function (user) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (user.userId == matchingUserId) {
            return resolve(true);
        } else if (user.type && user.type == matchingType) {
            return resolve(true);
        } else {
            // See if this user is one of your connections
            DB.getAdditionalUserInfo()
            .then(function (additionalUserInfo) {
                if (additionalUserInfo.a == user.userId)
                    return resolve(true);
                else
                    return reject(false);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                return reject(false);
            });
        }
    });
});
Promise.all(accessPromises).then(function (accessResults) {
    if (accessResults.every(result => result)
        res.ok();
    else
        res.notFound();
})
.catch(function (err) {
    res.notFound();
});
```

This does allow us to break after the 1st rejection, but any of the additional DB calls that were already started complete anyway.

This will work, and allow us to get the response back to the client faster, but still leaves a bit of wasted processing.

Comment: It would help if you showed some representative code.  But, if you want to stop when one request hits a condition, you probably want to use `Promise.all()` instead and just reject when you hit that condition.  As you appear to know already `Promise.settle()` will wait until all requests finish regardless of outcome.

Comment: Updated w/ changed code based on the suggestion. @jfriend00, I see you've taken issue with slow responses in the past, fire at will.

Comment: So, now that you've rewritten to use `Promise.all()` which is what I suggested in my answer, what question do you still have?  Or, has your original question now been answered?  FYI, the code you added suffers from the [Promise Anti-Pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) where you are creating promises that you do not need to create when you should just be returning the promises you already have.

Comment: If you want to carefully minimize the work you do to the absolute minimal amount of processing, then you can't fire N requests in parallel.  You would have to run them sequentially in order to make sure you don't launch the next request if it isn't needed.  This is because there's no way to undo an async request once you've already initiated it.  It has been sent and is already running at that point.  Of course, if you run things serially, then it may take longer to get your final answer so it is a tradeoff and you have to decide which is better for your particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Promise.all()` instead of `Promise.settle()`.

`Promise.all()` will finish when the first promise it is passed rejects and will not wait for the rest.  So, you can test your condition and then reject and then `Promise.all()` will also reject immediately.

`Promise.settle()`, on the other hand, will wait until all requests finish, regardless of outcome.

If you showed some representative code, we could help you much more specifically.

Here's a made up example:

```
function getUser(name) {
    // code that returns a promise whose fulfilled value is a user object
}

function getUserTestField(name) {
    return getUser(name).then(function(user) {
        if (!user.someField) {
            return Promise.reject({status: false});
        } else {
            return user;
        }
    }, function(err) {
        return Promise.reject({errCode: err});
    });
}

var promises = ["bob", "ted", "alice"].map(function(name) {
    return getUserTestField(name);
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(users) {
    // all users had field set to true
}, function(err) {
    if (err.status === false) {
        // at least one user has the field set to false
    } else {
        // some other type of error here
        console.log(err.errCode);
    }
});
```

Comment: @gotmikhail - Did this answer your question?  Part of being a good citizen on stack overflow is providing feedback to folks who provide answers to your questions and not just posting a question and then disappearing for some number of days.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I posted my question yesterday and planned on following up today. Your statement seems rather accusatory and is frustrating.

Comment: @gotmikhail - Well stack overflow is much more interactive that other types of online forums.  Posting and then following up the next day is not really how this place works.  Questions often get closed or downvoted if they aren't clear and the OP isn't answering questions within a few hours.  You should post questions at a time when you can follow up several times within the next few hours. I provided you an answer and I'd like to know if this answered your question or whether you need additional help or whether I should just delete the answer because its off target.

Comment: @gotmikhail - I'm still wondering whether this answer provided an answer to your question or not.  And, if not, please help me understand what else you need help with.